# Make video window bigger in HTML

Tags: html

my code is

```
 <embed src="videos/video.mp4" width="1450" height="500"  name="MediaPlayer" ShowControls="0" ShowStatusBar="0" ShowDisplay="0" loop="true">
```

i would like to make video window bigger but i can't, if i modify width or height, media player window doesn't change at all.
    what can i do to give more width and height to the video?

Comment: You should use the video-tag http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try on css like `embed{width:1450px;height: 500px}`